# bootstrap accordian collapse chevron icon with additional buttons

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I'm using bootstrap panels with accordion collapse to tidy up my page layouts. Each collapsible panel features a chevron on the right hand side of the title bar to provide the usual visual clues to functionality.

I want to add an button to the immediate left of the chevron, but I can't figure out how.

I've created a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eLb20n2t/4/) of my code to highlight the issue, but the panel header code is below.

```
<div class="panel-heading"><h4 class="panel-title"><a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#TS0002-collapsePanel-1">My title</a> </h4>
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs">Save <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save"></span></button>
    </div>    
  </div>
</div>
```

I've seen some examples of button groups on the right of panel headers, but the only examples of accordion collapse I've found use hrefs and I don't know how to merge the two. Any help would be gratefully received.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the button directly inside the h4, right next to the anchor link and then use css to align it to the right hand side, such that it appears next to the toggle chevron, like so:

```
<h4 class="panel-title">
    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#TS0002-collapsePanel-1">My title</a> 
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs mySaveButton">Save <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save"></span></button>
</h4>
```

Fiddle updated to show the same, including css and JS: https://jsfiddle.net/eLb20n2t/9/